# Getting started with PHP and Expression Web

Tags: php, expression-web

I want to build a basically interactive website with these tools. I need to make a navagation bar with a submenu. Ex:

**Services**

then when mouse is over **Services** it looks like:

```
 Services
    boo
    foo
```

I'm familiar with adding css styles, i'm just not sure about sub menus.

On the php side of things, I want people to select from the products and write their quantities, then I'd like a paypal button at the bottom which when clicked redirects to paypal and lists products ordered and their quantities (basically the paypal checkout page)

The other thing I want is a mailing list. I want people to be able to give their name and email and have a button that sends me an email so I can add them manually.

I would appreciate insight on any or all of these topics, maybe tutorials? I think I can manage the rest of the web site on my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too many questions at once.

Dropdown navigations can be done with HTML+CSS alone. You can also realize them with JavaScript. Since PHP is server-side, you would only generate HTML, CSS or JS from that (if at all)

If you are just getting started with PHP, you might best be off first reading the [PHP manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/). At least the chapter named Language Reference. There is also this [free book on PHP](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp) available.

[Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/) is also a good resource for beginners for any of the above topics. They have many good introductory articles, a good reference and many tutorials.

As for PayPal, consult the [PayPal developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/) to get information on how to integrate it.

Consider trying to build the page on your own first and then come back to ask individual questions, whenever you run into problems and googling them did not help.